# Add a Column to a DF with a "Yes" if any element of a row has a specific value in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to avoid an extremely long if_else statement, or even a nested for-loop to go through each row and look at their values.

But basically, I have a data frame that looks like this (30 columns, 50,000 rows):

```
Col1 Col2  Col3 Col4...Col30
Z     L    D     T     A
D     D    T     Z     X
L     G    T     A     J
....
```

If any row has the letter Z, a new column marker "result" will have a "Yes."  Other, it will have a no.

```
 Col1 Col2  Col3 Col4...Col30  Result
    Z     L    D     T     A    Yes
    D     D    T     Z     X    Yes
    L     G    T     A     J    No
    ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a logical matrix with `==`, get the `rowSums`, convert it to a logical vector and change it to values 1, 2 index and replace with 'No', 'Yes'

```
df1$Result <- c("No", "Yes")[(rowSums(df1 == "Z") > 0) + 1]
```

Or another option is `ifelse`

```
df1$Result <- ifelse(rowSums(df1 == "Z") > 0, "Yes", "No")
```

---

Or we can create the condition with `lapply` and `Reduce`

```
df1$Result <- ifelse(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1, `==`, "Z")), "Yes", "No")
```

---

all the three methods above are efficient because

1) Utilizing vectorized option

2) Not doing any regex when we can directly do the comparison (`==`)

Comment: WOW!  Thanks for all three of these ways of approaching the problem. I'll accept the answer once StackOverflow lets me!

Comment: Just did both!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that returns TRUE and FALSE into a new column

```
df1$Result <- apply(df1, 1, function(r) any(r %in% "Z"))
```

Or if you want to check if any column contains a Z OR L you can change the code to the following

```
test$Result <- apply(test, 1, function(r) any(r %in% c("Z","L")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R solution is to use `ifelse` + `grepl`, i.e.,

```
df$Result <- ifelse(grepl("\\bZ\\b",do.call(paste,df)),"Yes","No")
```

such that

```
> df
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col30 Result
1    Z    L    D    T     A    Yes
2    D    D    T    Z     X    Yes
3    L    G    T    A     J     No
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c("Z", "D", "L"), Col2 = c("L", "D", "G"
), Col3 = c("D", "T", "T"), Col4 = c("T", "Z", "A"), Col30 = c("A", 
"X", "J")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```